# Gradle Build failed?

Tags: java, android, ios, android-gradle-plugin, admob

i get this Build FAILURE every time i start a empty project

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'admob'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.1/google-services-3.1.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.1/google-services-3.1.1.pom'.
  >   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/216.58.211.238] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.1/google-services-3.1.1.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.1/google-services-3.1.1.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/159.122.18.156] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 1m 59s
Connection timed out: connect

Comment: You need internet access to solve this problem. Is it available?

Comment: i already run my android studio with internet access.. i think i need a proxy to download
@HosseinSeifi

Comment: Have you ip changer software? If so you need to set the proxy in android studio.

Comment: no i didnt change ip .. i was trying to add admob banner to an app ;;
but got stuck when trying to download ;; "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.2";;
@HosseinSeifi

Comment: can you suggest some " ip changer software" .. @HosseinSeifi

Comment: yes. I use freegate and also psiphon3

Comment: i did use freegate proxy but didnt work .. any suggestion plz @HosseinSeifi